# Fusion 7 on Macbook Pro Early 2011

Tags: macbook

I have been playing with Fusion 7 on my MBP.  16GB Ram, i7 @ 2.3 GHz, 500GB HDD.

Background:

Installed ESXi5.5 and vCSA ovf.  I set up the Host VM and vCS Appliance without any issues and it worked very well.

I created a Win2008R2 64-bit VM on my ESXi5.5 VM (nested in MBP via Fusion 7) to start playing with AD/DNS.  I setup AD/DNS via dcpromo.exe and began installing all the Windows Updates for the new VM.  After installing all updates VM rebooted and all worked fine.  I shutdown the VMs and my ESXi Host VM and powered off my MBP for the night.

Problem:

I came home from work and powered on my MBP but I am getting a grey screen of death after I type my user password and about 25% loading point on the Apple Bar it stops and Grey's Out....

What to do???

Thanks for you help in advance,

Newbster

Answer (score 0):

So after troubleshooting, it seems the RAM is the culprit.  I installed the Factory 8GB RAM and the MBP Booted ok.  I then shutdown and installed my 16GB RAM back in and it booted ok.

Weird...